# get data from nested array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am very new in mongodb. I just start my project using mongodb.In my project i need to get the data from nested array. I know there are too many questions related to this, but my problem is not solved. here is json.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58805a04469d401ab45943f6"),
    "siteId": 2,
    "guardGender": "MALE",
    "checkoutPoint": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("588098a025bad12cf01936d6"),
        "title": "string",
        "nfcCheckoutPoint": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5880c14683d042207896f7a4"),
            "title": "yup",
            "intervalTime": "string",
        }]
    }]

}
```

I need only nfcCheckoutPoint array.

```
"nfcCheckoutPoint": [{
                "_id": ObjectId("5880c14683d042207896f7a4"),
                "title": "yup",
                "intervalTime": "string",
            }]
```

This is my code which i am using

```
var criteria = {
                   _id: payloadData.siteId,
                   "checkoutPoint._id": payloadData.routeId,
                 "checkoutPoint.nfcCheckoutPoint._id": payloadData.checkpointId
                };
var projection = { nfcCheckoutPoint: { $elemMatch: { _id: payloadData.checkpointId }}}
 var option = {
                 lean: true
              };
Service.SiteService.getSite(criteria, projection, option, function (err, data) {

    if (err) {
        cb(err)
    } else {
        console.log(data)// this give me wrong values
    } 
})      


var getSite = function (criteria, projection, options, callback) {
    options.lean = true;
    Models.Site.find(criteria, projection, options, callback);
};
```

With this code i am getting:

```
 { "_id": ObjectId("58805a04469d401ab45943f6")}
```

Comment: `my problem is not solved` is too vague statement. What are you trying to solve? What is the problem you are facing? Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: You have mentioned "problem is not mentioned", but you forgot to describe the "problem". What is the expected output of the query? What do you get with your present query (error?)? What is inside the method `.getSite()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `aggregate` query

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
  { "$match": { _id: payloadData.siteId} }, //siteId = ObjectId("58805a04469d401ab45943f6")
  { "$project": {
    "checkoutPoint": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$checkoutPoint",
            "as": "cPoint",
            "in": {
              "_id": "$$cPoint._id",
              "nfcCheckoutPoint": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$cPoint.nfcCheckoutPoint",
                  "as": "nfcPoint",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq":  [ '$$nfcPoint._id', payloadData.checkpointId ] //checkpointId = ObjectId("5880c14683d042207896f7a4")
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "checkoutPoint",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$checkoutPoint._id", payloadData.routeId]}// routeId =ObjectId("588098a025bad12cf01936d6")
      }
    }
  }},
  {$project:{nfcCheckoutPoint:{$arrayElemAt: [ "$checkoutPoint.nfcCheckoutPoint", 0 ]}, _id:0}}
])
```

then **output** will be like:

```
{
    "nfcCheckoutPoint" : [ 
       {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5880c14683d042207896f7a4"),
          "title" : "yup",
          "intervalTime" : "string"
       }
     ]
}
```

Comment: I need only nfcCheckoutPoint array.